# How to use applescript to toggle the language setting of new dictation tool (10.8)

Tags: applescript

I really like the new dictation feature of MacOSX Mountain Lion. I am using it in two languages; english (u.s.) and french.

Each time I need to switch language, I have to go in system preference, Dictation and Speech, and select the language.

Now, I would like use Applescript to do that automatically , unfortunately, since it is so new, I cannot get the proper string of dictation module.

Quick example (this is just a start):

```
tell application "System Preferences"
   activate
   set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.xxxxxx"
end tell
```

for xxxx I tried "Dictation&Speech" a wild guess that did not work.

Any ideas on how I can get the exact string for "Dictation & Speech" ?

Thank in advance,

François

Comment: I would love to be able to change languages from German into English (UK) and vice versa via a script. Unfortunately I am quite new to AppleScript and therefore not very experienced. Would you mind posting your results once the script runs smoothly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

To get the id of a pane : go in system preference, select a pane, run this script in the Editor.

```
tell application "System Preferences" to get id of current pane
```

The result is the exact string.

Answer (score 3):

You could either edit property lists that store the setting and reopen the DictationIM process:

```
#!/bin/bash

k="com.apple.speech.recognition.AppleSpeechRecognition.prefs DictationIMLocaleIdentifier"
if [[ "$(defaults read $k)" == en-US ]]; then
  defaults write $k fr-FR
  defaults write com.apple.assistant "Session Language" fr-FR
else
  defaults write $k en-US 
  defaults write com.apple.assistant "Session Language" en-US
fi
killall -HUP DictationIM
```

Or use UI scripting:

```
delay 0.3 -- time to release modifier keys if the script is run with a shortcut
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Dictation" of pane "com.apple.preference.speech"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell pop up button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        click
        if value is "English (United States)" then
            click menu item "French" of menu 1
        else
            click menu item "English (United States)" of menu 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Comment: Wow! That works perfectly, thanks a million and sorry for the delay of my reply!

Answer (score 0):

Cool stuff!

If you have 'Notifications Scripting' installed ( http://www.cooperative-fruitiere.com/notifications/index_en.html ), then you can even have a notification informing you about the language.
And by the help of FastScripts, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to this script.

```
-- Switch the language of Mountain Lion's dictation
-- Here, we just toggle between English and German
-- Needs 'Notifications Scripting' ( http://www.cooperative-fruitiere.com/notifications/index_en.html )

delay 0.3 -- time to release modifier keys if the script is run with a shortcut
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Dictation" of pane "com.apple.preference.speech"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell pop up button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        click
        if value is "English (United States)" then
            set language to "German (Germany)"

        else
            set language to "English (United States)"
        end if
        click menu item language of menu 1
    end tell
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"

tell application "Notifications Scripting"
    set event handlers script path to (path to me)
    -- The user info parameter is a record. The supported data types are text, integer, real, boolean, date, alias, file and POSIX file.
    set dict to {theName:"Notifications Scripting", theVersion:"1.0", theScript:event handlers script path}
    display notification "Dictation Language" subtitle "Switched to:" message language
end tell

using terms from application "Notifications Scripting"
    -- This handler is called when a notification was delivered.
    on notification delivered title aTitle subtitle aSubTitle message aMessage actual delivery date aDeliveryDate user info aDict
    end notification delivered
end using terms from
```

Answer (score 0):

The script provided doesn't work unless you put in a `delay` command. Also, it needs to be `application process`, not simply `process`. Instead of explaining where to make the changes, I'll just post the working code. [Please note, this was tested on macOS Catalina. If apple changes the System Preferences GUI in future versions, this code may not work.]

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Dictation" of pane "com.apple.preference.speech"
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Preferences"
    tell pop up button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        click
        if value is "English (United States)" then
            click menu item "Hungarian (Hungary)" of menu 1
        else
            click menu item "English (United States)" of menu 1
        end if

    end tell
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Answer (score 0):

I now use Alfred to trigger this bash script. I assigned a hotkey to it and replicated it for the languages I speak, so I have three different keyboard shortcuts for my three languages. It uses a slightly modified script to the ones above (with a different `pref`, no longer requires `delay`s, and immediately triggers dictation.)

```
k="com.apple.speech.recognition.AppleSpeechRecognition.prefs DictationIMNetworkBasedLocaleIdentifier"

if [ "$(defaults read $k)" != "de_DE" ]
then
    defaults write $k "de_DE"
    defaults write com.apple.assistant "Session Language" "de_DE"

    killall -HUP DictationIM

-- Somehow I need to do twice the keyboard shortcut to start the dictation. This is the first one.
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to key code {63,63}'

fi


-- second one
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to key code {63,63}'
```